# Daemonizing python's BaseHTTPServer

Tags: python, daemon, basehttpserver

I am working on a daemon where I need to embed a HTTP server.  I am attempting to do it with  BaseHTTPServer, which when I run it in the foreground, it works fine, but when I try and fork the daemon into the background, it stops working.  My main application continues to work, but BaseHTTPServer does not.

I believe this has something to do with the fact that BaseHTTPServer sends log data to STDOUT and STDERR.  I am redirecting those to files.  Here is the code snippet:

```
# Start the HTTP Server
server = HTTPServer((config['HTTPServer']['listen'],config['HTTPServer']['port']),HTTPHandler)

# Fork our process to detach if not told to stay in foreground
if options.foreground is False:
    try:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid > 0:
            logging.info('Parent process ending.')
            sys.exit(0)            
    except OSError, e:
        sys.stderr.write("Could not fork: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
        sys.exit(1)

    # Second fork to put into daemon mode
    try: 
        pid = os.fork() 
        if pid > 0:
            # exit from second parent, print eventual PID before
            print 'Daemon has started - PID # %d.' % pid
            logging.info('Child forked as PID # %d' % pid)
            sys.exit(0) 
    except OSError, e: 
        sys.stderr.write("Could not fork: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
        sys.exit(1)


    logging.debug('After child fork')

    # Detach from parent environment
    os.chdir('/') 
    os.setsid()
    os.umask(0) 

    # Close stdin       
    sys.stdin.close()

    # Redirect stdout, stderr
    sys.stdout = open('http_access.log', 'w')
    sys.stderr = open('http_errors.log', 'w')    

# Main Thread Object for Stats
threads = []

logging.debug('Kicking off threads')

while ...
  lots of code here
...

server.serve_forever()
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is BaseHTTPServer somehow prevented from becoming daemonized?

Edit: Updated code to demonstrate the additional, previously missing code flow and that log.debug shows in my forked, background daemon I am hitting code after fork.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a bit of googling I [finally stumbled over this BaseHTTPServer documentation](http://pymotw.com/2/BaseHTTPServer/index.html#module-BaseHTTPServer) and after that I ended up with:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
  """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

server = ThreadedHTTPServer((config['HTTPServer']['listen'],config['HTTPServer']['port']), HTTPHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Which for the most part comes after I fork and ended up resolving my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do this with the [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) library:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import (HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler)
import contextlib

import daemon

from my_app_config import config

# Make the HTTP Server instance.
server = HTTPServer(
    (config['HTTPServer']['listen'], config['HTTPServer']['port']),
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler)

# Make the context manager for becoming a daemon process.
daemon_context = daemon.DaemonContext()
daemon_context.files_preserve = [server.fileno()]

# Become a daemon process.
with daemon_context:
    server.serve_forever()
```

As usual for a daemon, you need to decide how you will interact with the program after it becomes a daemon. For example, you might register a systemd service, or write a PID file, etc. That's all outside the scope of the question though.

In particular, it's outside the scope of the question to ask: once it's become a daemon process (necessarily detached from any controlling terminal), [how do I stop the daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517482/how-to-stop-a-daemon)? That's up to you to decide, as part of defining the program's behaviour.

Comment: Works great to start the daemon but how would I use it with start and stop commands? So far I wasn't able to stop the daemon.

Comment: How do you stop this daemon?

Comment: I repeat: you need to decide how you will interact with the program after it becomes a daemon. That includes making decisions about how the program will be stopped, since there is no longer a controlling terminal. A PID file, a SystemD service, etc. are all viable, but the choice is yours and it's not a necessary part of being a daemon.

Answer (score 2):

You start by instantiating a HTTPServer. But you don't actually tell it to start serving in any of the supplied code. In your child process try calling `server.serve_forever()`.

[See this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/654) for reference

Comment: Actually, I was running that after the fork, and according to my debug output, after the second fork, I am hitting code.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that worked for me was to override the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` method `log_message()`, so we prevent any kind of writing in stdout and avoid problems when demonizing.

```
class CustomRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def log_message(self, format, *args):
            pass

...
rest of custom class code
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) or some other similar script instead of rolling your own daemonizing process. It is much better to keep this off your script.

Also, your best option: Don't use BaseHTTPServer. It is really bad. There are many good HTTP servers for python, i.e. [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org) or [paste](http://pythonpaste.org/). Both includes ready-to-use daemonizing scripts.

Comment: Why exactly is it BAD? please, this is one of the top results in google... There are a massive amount of prebuilt python library's for http so more of a description of those would be amazing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since this has solicited answers since I originally posted, I thought that I'd share a little info.

The issue with the output has to do with the fact that the default handler for the logging module uses the StreamHandler.  The best way to handle this is to create your own handlers.  In the case where you want to use the default logging module, you can do something like this:

```
# Get the default logger
default_logger = logging.getLogger('')

# Add the handler
default_logger.addHandler(myotherhandler)

# Remove the default stream handler
for handler in default_logger.handlers:
    if isinstance(handler, logging.StreamHandler):
        default_logger.removeHandler(handler)
```

Also at this point I have moved to using the very nice [Tornado](http://tornadoweb.org) project for my embedded http servers.