# How to run the server in daemon mode in tornado?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I am working with Tornado and Python3. I need to run Dev server in daemon mode. But I found the python-daemon package, It is not supported for python3.2+. Here some code,

```
import daemon

from spam import do_main_program

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    do_main_program()
```

Can any one tell me python3.2+ supported package. Please give me some code for daemon mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17031227/1542900

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nginx Tornado and Flask - What's a good start/stop script and keep-alive method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557450/nginx-tornado-and-flask-whats-a-good-start-stop-script-and-keep-alive-method)

Answer (score 0):

Use Supervisor(A Process Control System).
http://supervisord.org/